# unable to analyze prometheus query

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

i have tried using below dahsboard.json from Grafana Labs for k8 cluster

```
https://grafana.com/dashboards/315/revisions
```

But it was very tough for me to understand the underlying queries used in json,is there better reference where i can start which will help in understanding these prometheus queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To figure out what each metric stands for, see cAdvisor's source code: https://github.com/google/cadvisor/blob/master/metrics/prometheus.go#L117

To understand the Prometheus queries used in this file, refer to the "Querying" chapter in Prometheus documentation: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/